# Default iPhone PhoneBook contact Notification to my APP whether some contact in the default contact app is modified or not

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Default iPhone PhoneBook contact Notification to my APP  whether some contact in the default contact app is modified or nor and if it is modified in which contact modification happened.

Can anyone suggest me some logic or API for that. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You won't be notified by the Contact App when a record is modified. You'll probably have to do it yourself: store the contacts and check for changes when your app become active. You can check the [AddressBook Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You can Get any changes fo address book via **ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback**
[This is  official documentation, refer it .](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback)

Comment: Its Very useful (But still one confusion related to it that if modification happened then which contacts are modified)